# Js программно сбросить кэш - ctrl+F5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня на сервере и в localStorage хранятся текущие версии приложения. Если они разные, то показывается экран обновления с кнопкой обновить. Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку кэш сбрашивался?

Приложение PWA, js и css кэшируется. В webpack.mix.js  `mix.version();` почти никогда не помогает почему-то. Но идея с этим экраном очень нравится, тк пользователь всегда знает об обновлении

Comment: А никак, через js не сбросить кеш. Для этого, нужно добавлять хеши в названия статики, типа main.4fe24ab19.js, чтобы браузер скачивал новый файл, а не из кеша брал, потому что в кеше не будет файла с новым хешем. Если юзаешь webpack, он умеет хеши добавлять.

Comment: А еще читал, что можно добавить просто приписку в файлам - ?version=xxx. Можно тогда попробовать приписывать текущую версию приложения

Answer (score 0):

В коде в env файле у меня прописывалась версия приложения. Например 0.8.
Сейчас я добавляю в index.blade.php (у вас это может быть index.php) 'суффикс' `?version={{env('APP_VERSION', 0.1)}}`. Таким образом, кэш будет сбрасываться, когда вы измените версию в env файле